Build succeeds, but rebuild fails on multi-framework project using MimeTypes nuget
I have a very strange issue with Visual Studio, whereby if I Build my project it works successfully, however if I Rebuild I get the following compile error
The application is a very simple, but does target multiple frameworks. (.NET 8 and .NET Framework 4.8)

CS0103    The name 'MimeTypes' does not exist in the current
context   MimeTypesRebuild (net48), MimeTypesRebuild (net8.0)

I have been able to replicate this issue in a clean console application, is this a bug with VS? Has anyone come across this before?
Project File:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net48;net8.0</TargetFrameworks>
      <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MimeTypes" Version="2.5.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Program.cs:
using MimeTypesRebuild;

var fileName = "sample.png";
var mimeType = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(fileName);

Console.WriteLine($"{fileName} has a MIME type of: {mimeType}");

Console.Read(); 


It's probably worth noting in the question that your sample is for a project called "MimeTypesRebuild". In most cases it doesn't matter, but as you're importing a source package that uses the default root namespace, it does in this case.

It looks like multi-targeting is the culprit, but it's not because you're actually targeting multiple frameworks - just using <TargetFrameworks>net8.0</TargetFrameworks> shows the same problem (at least for me). Using <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework> instead seems to be fine.

Based on my test, i am able to reproduce the same issue in VS2022(17.10.5) at my side. It seems an issue with VS. I found some user also reported this issue before. But it’s marked for inactivity.
Rebuild fails while build succeeds for multi-target project with NuGet package
I suggest you  can also create a new ticket to report this issue from VS Community:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect detailed information and do further investigation.
